# How do I use the ADB shell?

Tags: android, adb

How do I control my android phone with the ADB shell?

Pls show me the commands for ADB

Comment: Can you expand your question to show how it relates to programming?

Comment: What OS do you use; what exactly do you mean by "control my android phone" ?

Answer (score 3):

`adb shell` gives you an `ash` shell running on the device, which is an sh-compatible shell. So you've got the standard sh builtins: `cd`, `echo`, etc.

Then there are the command binaries on the `PATH`. My phone (Nexus One, Android 2.2.2) has the following:

```
$ ls /system/bin
logwrapper
logcat
nandread
linker
ionice
keystore
installd
hciattach
fsck_msdos
dumpsys
dumpstate
wpa_supplicant
dhcpcd
sleep
dexopt
vold
stop
bluetoothd
route
am
cmp
surfaceflinger
iftop
wipe
monkey
id
toolbox
insmod
sync
notify
cat
ioctl
top
dbus-daemon
rmdir
sh
date
ps
ifconfig
servicemanager
ln
netstat
vdc
sendevent
input
vmstat
schedtop
service
brcm_patchram_plus
mount
dd
bootanimation
tc
hd
getprop
ime
setprop
sdptool
ls
chown
log
run-as
pand
dmesg
schedtest
chmod
pm
kill
rm
df
rild
smd
dalvikvm
mkdir
reboot
omx_tests
bugreport
app_process
lsmod
svc
racoon
netd
dvz
akmd
umount
newfs_msdos
ndc
printenv
gzip
renice
watchprops
mv
bmgr
start
mediaserver
pppd
getevent
rmmod
setconsole
system_server
ping
mm-venc-omx-test
iptables
parse_radio_log
applypatch
dnsmasq
debuggerd
netcfg
mtpd
```

There are other directories on the `PATH`, but none of these are accessible (unless you've rooted your device?).

See also the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#shellcommands).

Comment: If you need more commands to control your device from `adb shell`, consider installing [Busybox](https://market.android.com/details?id=stericson.busybox&hl=en) on your android device. Busybox enables you to use most of the standard linux commands, such as file operations with `cp`, `wget`, `grep`, `tar` - which are very useful but not included in the standard adb command set.

Comment: Important to note that users must be rooted in order to use Busybox.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a device or an emulator connected run adb with parameter shell as in

`adb shell`

You can also type  `adb`  for commands and/or parameters to adb

For all this to work -  `adb`  must be in the path