# How to programmatically read Android file system from a .NET application?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, file

Given: When I plug my Android device into my Windows PC, Windows Explorer shows it as a device listed under My Computer, and gives me primitive access to its file system. The same goes when I plug in a media player or other devices.

Is there any way in the .NET environment to access the device's file system? Like, can it be accessed with the plain old System.IO File/FileInfo/FileStream objects, and if so how would I address the device?

What I am ultimately interested in is writing an application that will detect I have plugged in my phone, and have the application sync some files, move some files, and delete some files by my own defined rules. Accessing the device is my first hurdle and I'm finding it very difficult to search for online.

Comment: Well, did you try accessing it using System.IO.File? What were the results?

Comment: The problem is that I have no idea what file system address to try.

Something like:
var RootDir = new DirectoryInfo("My Android Phone. Look .NET, it's plugged in right there!!!");

Any ideas?

Comment: The easiest way is to figure out how to get the device mounted with a drive letter. Then you can treat it as if it were any other USB drive. If the android device doesn't support that, then run some sort of WebDAV or FTP server on the phone to serve the files up, see [Drive Letter MTP on Windows](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22979/drive-letter-for-mtp-connection-under-windows) and  [How to access Android File system from Windows 7 command line through USB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21619877/how-to-access-android-file-system-from-windows-7-command-line-through-usb)

Comment: mason, Yes! That is what these things are called! MTP Devices. I have some reading to do on my own, thank you thank you.

Comment: I decided I am going with FTP to do my syncing over Wifi. Thank you macon and thank you everyone who marked this as a duplicate for pushing me in the right direction!