# How can I move some specific files from my Android phone to my PC using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, cmd

I've written the following code to do copy .mkv files from my phone to my PC.

```
$source = "This PC\HUAWEI nova 3e\Internal storage\*.mkv"
$dest = "C:\Users\Kapil\Desktop\"
Copy-Item -Path $source -Destination $dest
```

But it gave me the following error:

```
Copy-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\Kapil\This PC\HUAWEI nova 3e\Internal storage' because it does not exist.
At line:3 char:1
+ Copy-Item -Path $source -Destination $dest
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\Kapil\...nternal storage:String) [Copy-Item], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

How do I set the correct source path? Is it possible to do this operation this way?

Comment: If you want a cmd solution add a CMD tag to your question and comment to me.

Comment: I'd appreciate if you can give the cmd solution.

Comment: I can only copy entire folders from phone to desktop.  Is copying the entire `This PC\HUAWEI nova 3e\Internal storage\` a problem?

Comment: I might be able to do just files from phone to PC if you download [ADB](https://www.xda-developers.com/install-adb-windows-macos-linux/), use `adb get-devpath` and if it reports the path to your internal storage tell me what it is.

Comment: Can you do this? `On your Android device: Settings->More Settings...->USB Utilities Press "Connect storage to PC" button and plug USB cable. Then press "Turn on USB Storage" and you will see new Drive Letter in My Computer assigned to your Phone.`

Comment: What OS version is on your phone?

Comment: Have you tried: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24361172/8826818

Comment: Add to your question: find your hardware [id](https://superuser.com/a/1420072/1003800). Connect your device and add the output of `Get-WmiObject -class win32_pnpentity -computername localhost | where-object {$_.HardwareID -like "*MTP*"} | format-list` Replace MTP with your hardware ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script is looking in the C: drive for your android storage. You need to provide the full path to the android phone, but I've had trouble with this in the past, since it's not a recognized drive (Like for instance C:), but you can use adb to pull files from android.

Have a look at this:
[Android: adb pull file on desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17629889/android-adb-pull-file-on-desktop)

Comment: Then I'll have to install ADB. Is it not possible without installing the adb?

Comment: It is looking for a drive letter, since as you can see it automatically assigned your source to the C: drive, since nothing else was provided. You also cannot mount the phone as a drive, have a look at this:
https://superuser.com/questions/1157661/how-to-mount-an-android-smartphone-as-a-drive-in-windows

So then, yes you would need to install adb to use powershell.