# Access Android Emulator Storage via Windows File System

Tags: android, windows, android-emulator, filesystems, mtp

I am trying to develop a file communication system that interfaces between the respective file systems of a Windows PC and a connected Android device.  I realize a better (or at least simpler) way to do this would probably involve using the `adb push` and `pull` commands, but I am gathering options/trying to avoid developing additional communications on the Windows side beyond its basic OS file access.  I know it is possible to interact with the device's storage directly from Windows when the device is physically connected via USB - if I understand correctly, this is commonly done using MTP?  However, I am also currently constrained to only being able to use an emulated Android device.  The Android Emulator is a useful tool for a variety of development situations, but I am not sure it was ever intended to appear as an MTP device in Windows like its physical counterparts do.

So could anyone provide documentation or some other resource establishing either

1. an MTP, UMS, etc. Windows connection is indeed not possible with the default QEMU Android Emulator; or
2. it is, and how.

Comment: `The Android Emulator is a useful tool for a variety of development situations, but I am not sure it was ever intended to appear as an MTP device in Windows like its physical counterparts do.` That is a nice observation. Never thought of that. But Android Studio can browse it with Device File Explorer so there is something.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the answer provided here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/21633596/1399272 - it does not appear that accessing the Android file system using a mounted drive in the Windows file system is an option, regardless of whether it is emulated or physically connected.  So my question becomes moot point.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to mount Android MTP device as a windows file system.

1. You need to install Dokany.
2. Use mtpmount command line exe

I tried this on my Samsung S21 and also Tab 10.  Both worked.